# Configure incoming e-mail for Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, smtp

I created a new installation of SharePoint2010. I am trying to configure the incoming e-mail but I seem not to find the link to do so.

I only get to see under E-Mail and Text Messages (SMS):
Configure outgoing e-mail settings | Configure mobile account

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this tutorial: [Installing and configuring SMTP and POP3 e-mail for sharepoint 2010](http://mosshowto.blogspot.com/2010/05/installing-smtp-pop3-sharepoint-2010.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's odd that the link is missing.  How is your farm set up?  The settings live at /_admin/IncomingEmail.aspx